# Web Api Claims Authorization for Specific EF Model Properties

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, authorization, claims-based-identity

With WebApi2 and Claims..

I have an Item Model, and an Item Controller.

I can decorate the Controller's Get with the folloiwing:

```
[ClaimsAuthorization(ClaimType = "FTE", ClaimValue = "1")]
```

How do I handle a scenario where a User/Role/Claim is used for permission to get the Item with or without, say, Items Cost or various other combinations of Model Properties?

Do I need to have distinct Controller Methods for each combination?  I researched Authorization Filters as they are "more granular" but have not found the solution.

My next research is to investigate DTO's and/or Partial JSON Responses.  Do those come into play with how to approach this? Thanks for any input!